# Recyclerlistview in react native onEndReached keeps firing

Tags: javascript, react-native, cross-platform, recyclerlistview

On Scrolling once, onEndReached keeps firing whenever there is new data in the list. Here is my code

```
<RecyclerListView
        style={AppStyle.flexOne}
        onEndReached={this.onScrollTillEnd}
        onEndReachedThreshold={Globals.LIST_SCROLL_THRESHOLD}
        layoutProvider={this.layoutProvider}
        dataProvider={this.state.dataProvider}
        rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
        scrollViewProps={{
          refreshControl: (
            <RefreshControl
              refreshing={initialFetch}
              onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
            />
          )
        }}
      />
```

Here is the function that is triggered on onEndReached

```
onScrollTillEnd = async () => {
  await this.fetchVisitorList();
}
```

whereas onEndReachThreshold is 0.1 and tried changing the value but no effect. Please help out